# What is the best way to present settings view controller in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder, xcode6

I have a main view controller with navigation bar on it and I want to present settings view controller when the user presses the appropriate button on the navigation bar. What is the best practice to present settings in iOS application? Modal / push / smth else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really depends on the interface you're going for. Push is straightforward, but sometimes you want the popover / flipside approach you get from a modal presentation. There is no best practice.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good candidate for "what is best" questions in any case. Voting to close on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what is you thinking, if its a simple settings, just create a UIPopover, if its complex, go to the push, or even a container for more dynamic way!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the "Present Modally" segue with a "Form Sheet presentation".
I think especially for the iPad layout that makes sense as the user does not loose the current context if he just quickly wants to make some adjustments.
Additionally, the settings in my apps consist of `UITableView`s which would look too stretched if I had chosen a full-screen layout here. Maybe I would consider choosing the full-screen layout with a `UISplitViewController` if my settings had more hierarchy and not just a couple of switches.

But this is just an opinion-base answer; there is no best practice here. Your choice depends very much on your UI and the general feel of your app.